# Hua Wei matebook e 2022 with Ubuntu 20.04 only works with nomodeset

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I have to use the nomodeset parameter to use Ubuntu 20.04; if I do not use the parameter, my screen will be blank white and twinkle.

My graphics device is an Intel Iris Xe, Cpu is i5-1130G7.

Using `nomodeset` causes the backlight controller to not work and graphics drivers not use Intel graphics drivers, How can I fix this?

I used all the solutions I can google, but it still does not work. Could it be a kernel error or BIOS drivers error?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I thinking about buying Matebook 2022 e for Linux. How it works with it?

Comment: i didn't and don't buy it

Comment: @rzlvmp, the issue is there for a Huawei Matebook E 2023. I would much appreciate if anyone shared any fixes/workaroudns/etc

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here, with a Matebook E 2022 with I7 CPU and also with Iris XE graphics. Booting Linux (Deepin, which is Debian-derived) with modesetting is not possible. I have to use either "nomodeset" or "i915.modeset=0" kernel parametter.

I have tried several kernel versions, some provided by the Deepin distro (5.15.24, 5.15.34) as well as some newer ones that I built from kernel.org sources (5.17.11, 5.18.6).

The newest kernel version I tested was 5.18.6.

The result is always the same. Enabling modesetting crashes the kernel. The screen goes black (probably the result of an unsupported mode being applied) and then the computer freezes and does not react to anything any more, also no more HDD activity. There may be (or not) a "kernel panic", but it's not visible because the screen is black. No reboot happens. The only way out is by long-pressing the power key to force a power-off.

With either "nomodeset" or "i915.modeset=0", the kernel boots and the rest of the Deepin system appears functional. However, the internal display panel brightness cannot be changed (always at maximum, which is eye-unhealthily bright) and external monitors are not recognized at all.

Something seems to be broken in the i915 driver (or in some configuration table from the BIOS that the i915 driver attempts to use) which causes the driver to crash and lock up the kernel during boot.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1233442)

Comment: Hello! Were there any updates? What did you end up doing? Are you still using this device with Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I have Matebook x pro 2022 with ubuntu then causing flicking, I used to fix this with:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
add GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.enable_psr=0"
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this can help. Btw I am doing research about installing ubuntu in Matebook E 2022 too. :)

Update:
Seems some of Chinese users have solved this Iris issue by upgrading kernel to 6.0.X, but there is still issue when moving mouse.

Comment: yes, it is still issue when moving mouse

Comment: Hello! Were there any updates since then? Did you try running Linux on any Huawei Matebook?